# How can I remove null from JSON object with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to remove an object from Json Object it works..but it replace it with null..i dont know why, how can i remove the null value from the json..heres the function :

```
company.deleteExternalLinkFromGrid = function (row, matricule) {
        // console.log('Inside of deleteModal, code = ' + code);
        //$scope.sitting= {};
       console.log(matricule);
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(linkJsonObj));
        delete linkJsonObj[matricule];

        console.log(JSON.stringify(linkJsonObj));
    };
```

heres the object:

> [{"name":"xxx","link":"www.ddd.com","id":0,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-001Z"},null,null]

Comment: Could you show us the object before the delete ?

Comment: [{"name":"xxx","link":"www.ddd.com","id":0,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-001Z"},{"name":"xxx","link":"www.ddd.com","id":1,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-0029"},{"name":"xxx","link":"www.ddd.com","id":2}]

Comment: Show please matricule. Is it key or index?

Comment: Issuing `delete` will not delete anything, it will just undefine values. The length of the array will be unaffected

Comment: Try `linkJsonObj.splice(linkJsonObj.indexOf(matricule), 1)`

Comment: Unless matricule is the index. In that case use `linkJsonObj.splice(matricule, 1)`

Comment: sometimes it deletes and somtimes not

Comment: ivar matricule is a key not an index..

Comment: @paperpaper You show an array of objects in your question. The null values are elements in the array, and an array does not have keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter()`,  `x` will be without null's.

```
function test()
{
    var x =[{"name":"xxx","link":"www.ddd.com","id":0,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-001Z"},null,null].filter(isNotNull);
    alert(JSON.stringify(x));

}

function isNotNull(value) {
  return value != null;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vn6r06o0/)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to delete an object from an array of objects in JavaScript. You don't need AngularJS for that, you can use VanillaJS.

If you just want the nulls filtered you can use

```
var yourArray =[{"name":"xxx","link":"www.ddd.com","id":0,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-001Z"},null,null];
     yourArray = yourArray.filter(function(elt){
     return elt != null;
    });
```

But this loses the original reference to your object.

If you want to keep the reference, Use array.splice().

```
  yourArray.forEach(function(){ 
      yourArray.splice(yourArray.indexOf(null),1);
  });
```

now you will have null less array in yourArray. This actually deletes an object from an array without changing the reference,

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Can you please at least support your statement with a simple example code?

Comment: Ok, will do, but the question is unclear. If paper-paper requires a new object or the same object reference

Answer (score -1):

`delete` will replaced the object with `undefined`

You can filter the array to remove them using `Array#filter()`

```js
var array = [{
  "name": "xxx",
  "link": "www.ddd.com",
  "id": 0,
  "$$hashKey": "uiGid-001Z"
}, {
  "name": "xx",
  "link": "www.dddcom",
  "id": 1,
  "$$hashey": "uiGrid-0029"
}, {
  "name": "xxx",
  "link": "www.ddd.com",
  "id": 2
}];

delete array[1];

array = array.filter(a=>a);

console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted, `filter` is the right way to filter out values from array.

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, you're right `delete` is not needed.